# gstreamer stop recording from alsasrc (line-in, cd, etc) on silence

Tags: gstreamer

The idea is to record from Line-In when here is sound (a tuner is connected to Line-In or CD).
What i want to now do is start the code, and automatically stop the recording when there is no sound for about 2 second. How should i go about doing this?

Something like Udpsrc property called "timeout".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the level element in the pipeline [1]. This will post the audio-level on the GstBus. You can e.g use a 1 sec interval and if two consecutive messages have a low rms (< -96) you post an eos to the pipeline.

Quick example (output edited):

```
GST_DEBUG="level:6" gst-launch-1.0 2>&1 audiotestsrc wave=silence num-buffers=10 ! level post-messages=true ! fakesink | grep ": RMS"
gstlevel.c:766:gst_level_post_message:<level0> message: RMS -700.000000 dB, peak -350.000000 dB, decay -350.000000 dB
gstlevel.c:766:gst_level_post_message:<level0> message: RMS -700.000000 dB, peak -350.000000 dB, decay -350.000000 dB
gstlevel.c:766:gst_level_post_message:<level0> message: RMS -700.000000 dB, peak -350.000000 dB, decay -350.000000 dB
```

[1] https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-level.html